# positioning two images in an overlay format

Tags: css, image, css-position

I have two images that I need to be layered side-by-side.
This is what image 1 looks like now, utilizing the following code:

```
            <section id="4" class="pt-sm-3 pt-md-5 pb-2">
            <div class="row text-center">
                <div class="col-md-1">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <img class="lazyload img-responsive product-images"
                         style="max-width: 100%; height: auto; margin: 0 auto;"
                         data-src="@Url.Content("./redImage.png")"
                         src="@Url.Content("~/Themes/21Rocs/Content/Images/loading(2).gif")" />
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <img class="lazyload img-responsive product-images"
                         style="max-width: 100%; height: auto; margin: 0 auto;"
                         data-src="@Url.Content("./blueImage.png")"
                         src="@Url.Content("~/Themes/21Rocs/Content/Images/loading(2).gif")" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
```

[image]

I would like to have the images overlay on top of each other like the following:
[image]
How would I go about setting that up in CSS?  I tried to use [this approach](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_image_text.asp) but can't get the layer to fit properly.  Please help.  Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use  negative margins to make these thing
I set a class to col-md-3  called overlay and  i styled this on style.css
Hope this works

```css
.overlay {
    margin-right: -100px;
}
```

```html
<link rel = "stylesheet" href="style.css">
 <section id="4" class="pt-sm-3 pt-md-5 pb-2">
            <div class="row text-center">
                <div class="col-md-1">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3  overlay">
                    <img class="lazyload img-responsive product-images"
                         style="max-width: 100%; height: auto; ;"
                         data-src="@Url.Content("./redImage.png")"
                         src="https://wallpapercave.com/wp/wp3260204.jpg" />
                </div>
                
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <img class="lazyload img-responsive product-images"
                         style="max-width: 100%; height: auto; ;"
                         data-src="@Url.Content("./blueImage.png")"
                         src="https://cdn.wallpapersafari.com/44/96/ow6U0D.jpeg" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
        </section>
```

Comment: Your guidance was very helpful.  I also added the z-index to finish the layer properly.

Answer (score 1):

Something like adding `position: relative; transform: translateX(-50px) translateY(-50px); z-index: -1;` as styling to the second image could be a quick fix. (You would probably need to amend the translateX/translateY values to get them where you need them - no other elements on the page will be affected by this transform)

Comment: Thank You.  the z-index was also needed to finish it.